# Changing image depending on count

Tags: asp.net, razor-2

Trying to create two buttons that will increase and decrease the current count and then output an image depending on the array count position
It will only go back and forth two images and i'm fairly new to this language so i can't see the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

```
@{
if(IsPost){
switch (Request.Form["userInput"]){
    case "Next":
        if (count < 7)
        {
            count += 1;
        }
        break;    
    case "Previous":
            if (count > 0){
            count -= 1;

            }
            break;        
    }   
    }
}

<form method="post">

<img src="Resources\@images[count]" alt="sample" />

<br />

<input type="submit" value="Previous" name="userInput"/>
<input type="submit" value="Next" name="userInput"/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of a submit button **can never** be used in the FORM. You'll just get that as a text on the button.

That's why you're not getting the value being sent to the server. Because submit button is just used to trigger the submit event. Not to submit a value to the form.

Comment: I have two buttons and depending on what button is pressed i want the image to change.